# error in writing procedure in Phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to write a stored procedure in Mysql phpmyadmin, the procedure is

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `shopping_portal`.`f_authenticate_admin`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE =`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `f_authenticate_admin`(l_username VARCHAR(50),l_password VARCHAR(50)) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
    DECLARE exist INT DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT count(*) INTO exist FROM admin WHERE username=l_username and password=MD5(l_password);
    RETURN exist;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

but it is throwing the error

```
 #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `f_authenticate_admin`(l_username VARCHAR(50),l_pas' at line 1
```

Help me in writing this procedure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well... did you actually read the error message? it says where your mistake is: `='root'@'localhost'`

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP. Removing the tag...

Answer (score 0):

Well, multiple issues:

You're mixing procedures and functions, those are two different stories. And you're probably looking for `DEFINER` with your `= root@localhost`. And you want to use single quotes instead of backticks (I'm not sure though, if that's really an issue). Anyway, let me rewrite it for you...

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `shopping_portal`.`f_authenticate_admin`;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' PROCEDURE `f_authenticate_admin`(IN l_username VARCHAR(50), IN l_password VARCHAR(50), OUT result tinyint) 
BEGIN
    SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM admin WHERE username=l_username and password=MD5(l_password)) INTO result;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

You then call it like this:

```
CALL f_authenticate_admin('test_username', 'a_password', @a_variable);
```

Then you have your result in `@a_variable`.

```
SELECT @a_variable;
```

Result is either 1 or 0.